# memory leak due to calling bitmapfactory

Tags: android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory

I wrote yesterday about memoryleaks and out-of-memory.

see my post:

[memory-leak and out-of-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174022/memory-leak-and-out-of-memory?noredirect=1#comment24867347_17174022)

I got some good tips to use memory profiler and I start using it and I may have found something but I could not solve it. In the DDMS one can choose to track allocation of objects. I found something interesting while clicking on a sublistitem (which loads 9 images into a scrollview). ) images should be allocated 9 times - but I could see that it is allocated 27 times. 9 times allocated due to the createScaledBitmap-method of Bitmap-class, then 18 times due to the call of the BitmapFactory-class. WHY???

I'll post the methods that scaledown the bitmaps below. Could the code be written better? Is it logic that resources are allocated 27 times for 9 images? am I calling BitmapFactory.decodeResource too many times for instance? But I could only recycle one time.

the importand method below is **decodeSampledBitmapFromResource**

Greatful for answers!!!

```
/**
       * 
       * @param options
       * @param reqW
       * @param reqH
       * @return
       */
      public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqW, int reqH) {

            int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
            int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
            int inSampleSize = 1;
            if (imageHeight > reqH || imageWidth > reqW) {
                int heightRatio = Math.round((float) imageHeight / (float) reqH);
                int widthRatio = Math.round((float) imageWidth / (float) reqW);
                inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
                System.out.println("i if-satsen!");
                System.out.println("height-ratio: " + heightRatio + "\nwidth-ratio: " + widthRatio);
            }
            System.out.println("samplesize: " +  inSampleSize);
            inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

            return inSampleSize;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        /**
         * 
         * @param res
         * @param resId
         * @param reqW
         * @param reqH
         * @return
         */
        public Bitmap[] decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int[] resId, int[] reqW, int[] reqH) {

            this.scaledBitmap = new Bitmap[resId.length];
            BitmapFactory.Options options;
            for (int i = 0; i < resId.length; i++) {
                options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId[i], options);

                System.out.println("ursprunglig bild: h = " + options.outHeight + " w = " + options.outWidth);
                options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqW[i], reqH[i]);

                while (options.outHeight < reqH[i] || options.outWidth < reqW[i]) {

                    options.inSampleSize--;
                    System.out.println("räknar nu ner insampleseize\ninSamleSize =" + options.inSampleSize);
                }

                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId[i], options);
                System.out.println("innan omskalning: h = " + options.outHeight + " w = " + options.outWidth);
                System.out.println("antalet bytes: " + bm.getByteCount());
                System.out.println("native free size: " + Debug.getNativeHeapFreeSize() );

                this.scaledBitmap[i] = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, reqW[i], reqH[i], true); 
                bm.recycle();

            }
            System.gc();
            return this.scaledBitmap;
        }
```